# Angular 2 dynamic form with multidimensional array

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm tyinng to build a form using multiple reusable sections. I'm using a json object to keep the form data. Form is building without an error. I am using angular reactive forms. So I can't add formArrayName name. it when I add it showing error. Is it must formAraryName? Because without it when I select a dropdown and load another select dropdown data base on first one, the first time it loads correctly. But when I push another group to the array and select an option in first dropdown it change all second dropdown values. How can I load data without changing previeous ones.

Form looks like

[image]

code

[image]

ui examples

1st time

[image]

2nd time

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this repository here can help you.

https://github.com/indrajeetgajbhiye/reactiveFormsDemo

Dynamic formArray implementation upto 3 layers. You can extend it as per your wish.